# Can I using azure services rbac with on-premise authenticate without sync user to AAD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, rbac

Can one use ADFS/pass-through authentication to authenticate to Azure service (Portal) by on-premise AD without synchronizing user accounts? Can one assign  RBAC for an on-premise user with Azure services?
For example, grant a VM contributor role to an on-premise user without sync all user information between on-premise AD and AAD.

Comment: no, as the existing answer says, this is not possible. how would AAD know about your on premise AD?

Answer (score 2):

You need to sync users to Azure AD. Password hashes do not need to be synced, you can use ADFS for login. But you do need to sync users so Azure AD knows what users exist.

Comment: Thanks juunas
I reference this tutorial, but that said we need sync and create user@domain.onmicrosoft.com. Can we sync the same domain user (not repplica to onmicrosoft.com domain) and authenticate it by adfs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tutorial-federation

Comment: You can add your custom domain to Azure AD and they can use e.g. `first.last@company.com` usernames. onmicrosoft.com is the default domain name. Ah, but yes, the admin account that sync uses needs to be onmicrosoft.com in this case. It can't use your domain since you are not syncing password hashes.

Comment: That tutorial looks good otherwise though, that should give you the federation you need.